# Partition Equal Subset Sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

LC: https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/

So the formula that allows one to calculate dp[i][j], where if there is a combination out of the first i'th elements that sum up to j is:

```
dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - nums[i - 1]] || dp[i - 1][j];
```

The first half before the OR operator represents what happens when we SELECT the I'th Element.

My question is why is it `j - nums[i - 1]` and NOT `j - nums[i]`.

Shouldn't we minus the current sum(j) by the current 'weight' (nums[i]) of the i'the element and see if the first i - 1 elements can sum up to it?

Why do we minus the value of the previous element?

Comment: I think you are right with `j - nums[i]` (while I don't see where is citation)

Comment: Got it from:https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/discuss/90592/01-knapsack-detailed-explanation

Comment: Note that textual description before code is correct `Thus, the transition function is dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] || dp[i-1][j-nums[i]]`

Comment: Very strange because the solution with the 'wrong code' passes on LC...

Comment: OK, I see the source of inconsistency. Answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that table contains `n+1` rows, and we can see in more full code that `i` index goes from `1` to `n`, so `nums[i-1]` refers to zero-based items of `nums[]` in range of index `0..n-1`

```
   for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < sum+1; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            if (j >= nums[i-1]) {
                dp[i][j] = (dp[i][j] || dp[i-1][j-nums[i-1]]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok so both answers work and the j - nums[i - 1] 'style' is just to account for how they built the matrix?

Thanks a lot!!